# Is it possible to have different required fields per page layout?

Tags: page-layout

We have 2 page layouts (i.e. *PageLayout A*, and *PageLayout B*)
*PageLayout A* `require field` "*customername*" but not require "**productname**"
*PageLayout B* `require field` "*productname*" but not require "**customername**"

How can we accomplish this feature because if we set `require field`s for both *fields*, we have to *input* the value in every page layouts?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

It turns out that we can set the content type per page layout which mean we can specific fields for each content type.

Regards,

Andy

Comment: Yes, content types are the way to go for your requirements.  You should mark your answer as the answer so it shows up as the first answer when other users come to this page.

Answer (score 1):

Using `PreSaveAction` function could be a solution. (Right before item is submitted to server, SharePoint checks for a function called `PreSaveAction` and if it exists, it sends item to server only if that function returns `true`.

You would know which layout is loaded within `document.location.href` string property.

```
var field_productname = document.querySelector('[title="productname"]').value;
var currURL = document.location.href;
if(field_productname == '' && currURL.indexOf('PageLayoutA') == -1) {
    // Set error message
    return false;
}
else
    return true;
//...
```